# Add tuple values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a script where I have a list of tuples

```
tuple=()
number=input("Enter the how many elements you want :")
for i in range(0,number):
     ele=input("Enter the element :")
     tuple.apppend(ele)
print tuple
```

Append method cannot work

Comment: Well that is what a `list` is for. A tuple is immutable.

Comment: Yes, if you could append arbitrary values to a tuple it wouldn't be a tuple.

Comment: This is not a list of tuples, it is just a tuple, that you want to fill with strings.

Comment: that mean's append method cannot work in tuple

Comment: Also there's a typo in `apppend`: correct would be `append`

Comment: @kaviraj: yes, it does not makes sense to do that. Lists have order, tuples have structure.

Comment: Why is this tagged as Python 3 when it's clearly Python 2?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it by creating your tuple-inputs from a list like so:

```
def GetTuple():
    data=[]
    number=input("Enter the how many elements you want :")
    for i in range(0,number):
        ele=input("Enter the element :")
        data.append(ele)

    return tuple(data)


myTup = GetTuple()
print(myTup)
```

If you need multiple tuples you have to call this multiple times and put each tumple inside another list. After the tuple is created, you cannot modify it.

Comment: @kaviraj Exactly, that is the reason to collect all values stored inside that tuple into a list and converting that into a tumple at the end. The resulting tuple is immutable. If you need to mutate the values of your tuples, then you should not use them but use lists instead.

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types), meaning that their value cannot be changed where they're stored in memory, but rather pointing the *variable* to a different instance in memory.

Therefore, it does not make sense to have an `append()` method for an immutable type. This method is designed specifically for [lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

In your case, you might want to switch to a list rather than a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

> Append method cannot work

Exactly. Tuples are immutable. So provide all contents *during creation*. Like:

```
elements = tuple(input('Enter the element: ') for _ in range(number))
```

Demo:

```
>>> number = input('Enter the how many elements you want: ')
Enter the how many elements you want: 3
>>> elements = tuple(input('Enter the element: ') for _ in range(number))
Enter the element: 3.142
Enter the element: 2.718
Enter the element: 42
>>> elements
(3.142, 2.718, 42)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tuple=()
number=int(input("Enter the how many elements you want :"))
for i in range(number):
    ele=input("Enter the element :")
    tuple = tuple + (int(ele),)
print(tuple)
```

This works on Python 3.6.

Comment: please give more explanation for your solution

Comment: It works everywhere. But it creates a new tuple everytime instead of adding elements into existing one (what is impossible by definition).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `tuple.append(ele)` you could do `tuple += ele,`<sup>[*]</sup>. It's less efficient because it copies the whole tuple every time, but since you apparently have a person enter data manually, I assume it won't be much.

Btw, don't call it `tuple`. You're shadowing Python's built-in, plus you'd better use a meaningful name that *describes the contents*.

<sup>[*] To the inevitable noobs ignoring the comma and claiming that that doesn't work: Don't ignore the comma, and do test it.</sup>